# CSS - Scrollbar appear on Table cell if window is too small

Tags: javascript, html, css

OK, i have been digging through but haven't found a solution to my problem
I will try to explain as best as i can.

I have a website created in tables (*don't ask*), this site have a non fixed top menu composed of a table row with three table columns, one for a image logo, one for a name and the last one for buttons as a menu, the logo and the name are on the left side.

The menu is the issue here, it's composed of a single `ul` element with fixed width `li` elements. here is a small example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="logo.png"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span>COMPANY NAME HERE</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li style="width: 100px">button 1</li>
                <li style="width: 100px">button 2</li>
                <li style="width: 100px">button 3</li>
                <li style="width: 100px">button 4</li>
                <li style="width: 100px">button 5</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The menu has grown and now has far too many buttons., on smaller screen this creates a horizontal scrollbar on the entire page.

This is my task, and so my problem now, i have to create a horizontal scrollbar (*again don't ask*) on the menu buttons if the window is too small to fit them all, but only in the buttons.

For reference, the `li` elements have both the `display: table-cell` and the `display: inline-block` properties, it seems that the table-cell is overriding the inline-block

EDIT:

Sorry, forgot to add: buttons appears horizontally. here is the CSS for the current `li`

```
text-align: center;
position: relative;
font-size: 12px;
text-transform: uppercase;
display: inline-block;
background: linear-gradient(-35deg, transparent 40px,rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 41px,rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 86px,transparent 87px);
min-width: 120px;
display: table-cell;
```

and the `ul` itself have the following CSS:

```
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
```

Comment: I know I shouldn't but..... why?

Comment: From the current code, the buttons are appearing vertically so why do you have horizontal scroll bars? Can you include all the relevant css/html code?

Comment: Where is your css? Mark the attribute as !important

Comment: for the table system It's a legacy code we have to maintain, it's to complex and will take some time to get rid of it....for the "solution", it's what my higher ups came with, and i can't think of another way without taking that table away

Comment: You should seriously convince them to forget about these tables... anyway, this here http://jsfiddle.net/0ae0xsb4/ works, you only need to set the max-width via javascript. I think in pure CSS it might be hardly possible...

Comment: I edited the question with the CSS for the li and the ul, buttons appears horizontally

Comment: so just style the table / ul to  overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:hidden; and set the body to overflow:hidden;

Comment: the issue i think is with the fixed with li, even if i style the ul with overflow it just wont scroll, but i will try Tom's solution by setting the width on the ul with javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a mix of a CSS and JS solution for you, which also works on window resize.

It is not pretty ( but what you are asking is not either! :P )

To use `overflow-x`, you need to set a fixed `width`.

Just add a class to the menu td, like `<td class="menu">` (just for better targeting).

Now on CSS, add this:

```
td.menu {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

With JS, you can now grab the BODY element width (or whatever other container element you see fit) and update the `.menu` `max-width` with that value, on script load and window resize.

This is the complete JS:

```
var menuW, bodyW;
var updateSize = function() {
  // Get the menu size
  menuW = $(".menu").width();
  // Get the body size
  bodyW = $("body").width();
  // Update menu with body size
  $(".menu").css("maxWidth", bodyW);
}

// If you need this to happen on window resize
$(window).resize(function() {
  updateSize();
});

// Update the size at the script load
updateSize();
```

See a working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/fabio_silva/thrbgz4o/

Answer (score 0):

this code might work :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if($('table tr td').innerHeight()<120)
$(this).css('overflow-y','scroll');
});
```

Comment: why the javascript? its totally doable with just css... and this was not tagged jquery..

Comment: To be honest a javascript solution is ok, i would prefer a pure CSS solution but i'm up for ANY solution at this point

Comment: u have added javascript tag in this question . that's why i gave u the js solution .

Comment: @NiharSarkar that's JQuery though

Answer (score 0):

Ok i finally found a solution, it's a very, **VERY** ugly solution as the *TRUE* solution is to get rid of the tables. but it's a solution nonetheless.

I added the following javascript code on the bottom of the page:

```
if(window.innerWidth <= 1880){
    document.getElementById('top-menu-buttons').style.width = (window.innerWidth - 390) + 'px';
}else{
    document.getElementById('top-menu-buttons').style.width = '';
}
```

with a similar code wrapped in a `window.onresize = function()` block just in case, the `ul` now have the following css:

```
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
overflow-x: auto;
```

Thanks to **Tom Doodler** and everyone for the help.